# How to refresh a folder via command prompt?

Tags: cmd.exe

I shared a directory via samba in Linux. In Win10 I mounted that directory as a network drive. I edit one script in Linux in that directory and I need to run it in Win10 via command prompt.

However, when I make the chage, I have to press F5 in Win Explorer and then with shift and right click open the command prompt every time to have a newest version of that file.

Is there a way in Win command prompt to automatically refresh and run last version of that file?